# Session time out during uploding file to datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi

i have isci san which has 2 LUNs. The first one is a ntfs filesystem and the second one is a datastore where the esxi gets the virtual machine. Now i need to copy a virtual machine from the ntfs lun to the datastore. The only way(at least its the only one i know) to do this is to use the virtual infrastructure client to upload this files.

The problem is that i'm getting time out error when i upload the vmdk disk file.

The questions are:

Is there a fast way to copy the virual machine from the ntfs lun to the datastore?

Is there a way to inrease the timeout value?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the file from the NTFS-formatted iSCSI mount to a local drive on the machine you're running VI/VSClient from, then from their copy it to the VMFS-formatted iSCSI mounted datastore via the VI/VSClient - if that works then I guess you just have a performance issue with your iSCSI array/device. If it doesn't you may have a data corruption of one form or another.